# Vite manifest not found at: D:\Laravel\test\public\build/manifest.json

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-9

#### What I did

I created a fresh Laravel project using the command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^9.0 test
```

and then I ran:

- 1. command prompt:

```
php artisan serve
```

- 2. command prompt:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm i
npm run dev
```

#### Problem with `@vite()`

[image: Laravel Error]

#### Expected result

[image: Example Auth Page]

#### More information

###### package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.56.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your scripts entry on your package.json file?

Comment: you do not even have `vite` installed

Comment: do I need that? I just followed the tutorial the teacher gave and got errors

Comment: your package.json tells that you are using laravel mix and not vite

Comment: so should I change that or what do you suggest I do?

Comment: search for laravel mix and vite first, they are called package managers. i advise to go to laravel mix first since it seems like you are a begginer. laravel mix is easier to use for a beginner.

Comment: ok, but what should I change in my project to fix that error?

Comment: Cause if I search laravel mix on google it just tells me how to create a new project (which it already is)

Comment: I suggest to use the latest version instead. `composer create-project laravel/laravel test` vite is pre-installed in the package.json. If you run `npm run build`, it will generate the assets correctly. If you run `npm run dev`, you **may** need to update the vite config file to point to the correct assets (different search).

Comment: using the latest version worked ty

Comment: also, I dont mind it being confusing, cause I can just learn that, my problem was that a fresh unedited project didnt even work

Answer (score -1):

#### Laravel UI 4.x

The `laravel/ui 4.x` supports `Laravel 9`, but it's important to note that the updating of these packages will commence after the official release of `Laravel 9`. Therefore, they are unlikely to work with `9.0`, according to information from packagist.org, even the `laravel/ui 4.0.0` requires at least `Laravel 9.21`.

[`laravel/ui@4.0.0` requirements](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/ui#v4.0.0) - packagist.org

#### Laravel UI 3.x

So it can be concluded that you are using `laravel/ui 3.x`. Specifically, version `3.3.3` or higher but less than `4.x`. As these versions all provide support for `Laravel 9.0`.

[`laravel/ui@3.3.3` requirements](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/ui#v3.3.3) - packagist.org

#### Laravel UI 3.4.6

I assume you chose version `3.4.6`, as it's advisable to have the most recent versions whenever possible.

[`laravel/ui@3.4.6` Github Repository](https://github.com/laravel/ui/tree/v3.4.6) - github.com

It is evident from the `README.md` that it's `laravel/ui 3.x`, so even the `3.4.6` version utilized Laravel Mix, which is a webpack JavaScript compiler. Vite was exclusively introduced starting from version `4.x`.

So, the error message shows that there is a blade error, as using `@vite` directive would invoke Vite, but for your case, you should be using `mix()` function instead.

### Solution (Laravel 9.20 or lower)

###### Wrong (current for Vite, but you used Webpack by Laravel Mix)

```
@vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

###### OK (for Laravel Mix)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('resources/sass/app.scss') }}">
<script src="{{ mix('resources/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

### Recommendation (Laravel 9.21 or higher)

**I suggest using Vite instead of Webpack.** Several tests support this decision, and you can research it further online. **Laravel has also officially switched to Vite.** If possible, consider using the latest version in the `9.x` series, but preferably `Laravel 10`.

---

#### Updated

[image: your laravel version]

The error message reveals from your screen that you have been using version `9.52` since the installation. However, both `Laravel UI 3.x` (`Laravel 9.0+`) and `Laravel UI 4.x` (`Laravel 9.21+`) support version `9.52`. You likely installed version `9.0` initially, then installed `Laravel UI 3.x`, and subsequently updated Laravel. Composer probably didn't notify you about a conflict with the `laravel/ui` package, as version `3.x` provides appropriate support for this as well.

Unfortunately, this is a major version change, so the `composer update` command wouldn't have taken it into account. By the way, I use an extension in Visual Studio Code that indicates the available latest version for each package in the composer.json file. This way, I can quickly see if I don't have the right version installed somewhere for some reason.

[`Composer` extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.composer-php-vscode) - DEVSENSE, VSCode Marketplace